# Count clicks on one button, save it to MYSQL and then display the current value (AJAX, PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is what I want to accomplish on http://geheimprojekt.nomachines.org/

1. User clicks on "Nochmal!" Button (New word combination is generated)
2. Send the click to my MySQL database (withou reloading the page), increase "clicked" row by 1
3. Update the text in a paragraph "n Word combinations have been generated so far."

This is my first attempt to work with AJAX.
I have jQuery knowledge but i can't connect the dots it seems.

The SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sggcount` (
  `counter` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german2_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sggcount`
--

INSERT INTO `sggcount` (`counter`) VALUES
(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work is very simple. You need some html for the future div where you want to place the couting:

```
<div id="counting"></counting>
```

Then right at the end of the generator() function you add this:

```
function generator(){
    /*your code here...*/    
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id", "result");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(element);
    /*the ajax code here*/
    var url='urltophpfile/phpfile.php';
    $.get(url,function(data){
        $('#counting').html(data+' Word combinations have been generated so far.');
    });
 }
```

Now in your phpfile.php file you will need the code to increment the count. I guess you know how to do this part if now i can help with it too. I'll add some sample code here so you have an idea.

```
<?php
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'db-sgg', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to database server');
  mysql_select_db('db1152127-sgg') or die('Cannot select database');
  $databasecall = mysql_query("SELECT counter FROM sggcount WHERE counter > 1");
  /*so here you select the already stored value and then you make an update to increment it*/
  mysql_query("UPDATE sggcount SET counter=counter+1");
  $count = mysql_fetch_assoc($databasecall);
  echo $count['counter']+1;
?>
```

By doing the echo above you will return the incremented value and the ajax will display it.

## Update 1

Added more comprehensive php code

NOTE: if you add the jquery script please change the generator function to use jquery.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still need more information. Its hard for me to make it work together. I'll muddle through ;-)

Comment: Well what is the information you need exactly i could help you with it.

Comment: I basically need a sample of the PHP, JQuery and MYSQL needed. I'm not sure how ti glue it together right now.
Maybe I'm asking too much and need to read more on this first.

Comment: This is my PHP `<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'db-sgg', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to database server');
mysql_select_db('db1152127-sgg') or die('Cannot select database');

    $databasecall = "SELECT * FROM sggcount WHERE counter > 1";
    /*so here you select the already stored value and then you make an update to increment it*/
    "UPDATE sggcount SET counter=counter+1";
    echo $databasecall['counter']+1;
?>`

Comment: Well do you have the MYSQL table and the php code? The jquery part is done in my above answer. All you need to do is copy paste the code to your generator function. If you need help with the ajax file i can help with that but you have to tell me the table and how it is formed.

Comment: I updated the answer check it out now. You needed mysql_query to run it.

Comment: Aaah! *Light bulb in head explodes* Now i get closer. Let me fiddle around a bit... :)

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot man. I'm really happy now :) A very simple solution indeed. Now it all makes sense. I learned a lot.

Have a nice weekend!

Comment: My next idea would be to update the Word combinations in real time (or ate least every 5 seconds...) I'll look around :)

Comment: Just to help you out. If you want to do the update in real time. What you need to do is to lose the last part of the ajax: `$('#counting').html(data+' Word combinations have been generated so far.');` and then make a new function on document load that has a `setInterval()` and executes at every 5 seconds and updates the count. Pretty easy if you make a new question i can give you an example if nobody does before me.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you could bind click event to your button and make ajax request.

- [JQuery ajax doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

On server side your PHP page should update SQL data.
Follow Javascript demo code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button-selector').click(function(){
        //use jquery ajax call to call php server page that update SQL data
        $.ajax({
              url: "updateClick.php",
             context: document.body
             }).success(function() { 
                     //success callback
             });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

to send AJAX request on clicking use:

```
$('#button').click(function(){ // when user `click` element with `id="button"` (#button)
 $.ajax({ // Start AJAX call
  url: 'accept.php', // URL to send AJAX request
  success: function(data) { // Function to execute on SUCCESS reply (reply data as paramenter)
    var cc = $('#clicks_count').html(); // In your element with `id="clicks_count"` you store your click count (`<a id="clicks_count">21</a>`). Assign to `cc` javascript variable value of clicls_count
    $('#clicks_count').html(cc + 1); // Increasing clicls_count on 1 and write it to `<a id="clicks_count">22</a>`
  }
});
});
```

At accept.php use script increasing clicks counter by 1.

Comment: I think I have to learn so much more. The combination of these things confuses me. Let me try your suggestions. I'm still not very clear on the AJAX part.

Comment: Take a look at moified answer with comments