# Vote +1 or -1 in Wordpress using on multiple parts

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have made a custom wordpress post type, containing multiple parts of content, each pulled out of the database in the same way.

Now I want to make a vote up and a vote down, showing the results without page refesh, and updating the score in the database. Much like stackoverflow + and - vote.

Here I found the solution, but I cannot get the code transferred to wordpress: 
 [Count clicks on one button, save it to MYSQL and then display the current value (AJAX, PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245693/count-clicks-on-one-button-save-it-to-mysql-and-then-display-the-current-value)

I try something like this, which code do I need in wordpress syntax?

One big problem is, each block is built from the database, so how can I make a unique + and - button for each of them, and writing it back to the right database row? I can insert the ID from each part in the class and then read this class out and write to the appropriate field in the database?

My try:

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->update( 'my_database', array( 'vote' => $vote + 1 ), array( '%d') );


/*so here you select the already stored value and then you make an update to increment it*/
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT vote FROM my_database WHERE part_id = "??" );

$vote = mysql_fetch_assoc($myrows);
echo $vote['vote']+1;
```

Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each item you are tracking has a unique identifier (part_id), there are two ways this can be done:

1. Create a new table with values part_id, plus_counter, minus_counter
   OR
2. Append to your existing table part_id, plus_counter, minus_counter

When the user is viewing that specific part, query the existing table based on part_id and display accordingly.

Markup Code:
SELECT plus_counter, minus_counter FROM table_name WHERE part_id='$part_id'

Comment: Thanks mlishn, any help with the syntax, if I take this code to wordpress database connection syntax I get lost, which parts do I have to keep / translate to get it working?

Comment: In your wordpress setup, you would need to either make a new table or append to the existing table. You could do this with the PHPmyadmin plugin. CREATE table_name (id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT, part_id int(11), plus_counter int(11), minus_counter int(11), PRIMARY KEY (part_id)) OR Just add in the same types to existing table. Then the query would be : $wpdb->get_results("SELECT plus_counter, minus_counter WHERE part_id=??") Hope I could help. Please vote up and accept this answer :)